# Is there a way to round or ceil BigInteger?

Tags: c#

I have a BigIntiger, say 1234567890 and I'm looking for the fastest possible way to turn that into something like one of these:

- 2000000000
- 1300000000
- 1234567900

Comment: 3 outputs for every input?

Comment: Any of those would be acceptable. I'm just trying to round the number up so when I divide it by some other number there is no remainder.

Comment: If that's what you want then the solution seems pretty clear. Either (1) divide it by that number and then multiply it by that number, or (2) find the remainder and subtract it.

Comment: I also note that you are not looking for the fastest possible way, as you are likely unwilling to spend millions of dollars on custom hardware to solve this problem in picoseconds rather than the nanoseconds it takes. You are looking for an *acceptably fast solution given a certain budget*, like we all are.

Comment: As fast as is possible for me. Your solution is pretty obvious now that I check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is built-in way of doing so.

The easiest way to get "no remainder" is to just decrease value by remainder:

"Rounded" to not give remainder for 13:

```
  var x = new BigInteger(123456);
  var roundedTo13 = x - (x % 13);
```

Or to 100:

```
  var roundedTo100 = x - (x % 100);
  Console.WriteLine(roundedTo100);
```

If you need rounding in more traditional sense - check if remainder is greater than value you want to round by and sign of number you want to round. If value of remainder (x % 100) is greater than half you'd need to add/substract 100.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to split the string. Although there may be performance issue, the result is OK.

```
    //n=1, 2, 8 to check for your example
    static long F(long num, int n)
    {
        string all = num.ToString();
        long headn = Convert.ToInt64(all.Substring(0, n)) + 1;
        return (long)(headn * Math.Pow(10, all.Length - n));
    }
```